# Setting margin and padding for <input type='radio' /> in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to get the CSS to modify my radio buttons. Their default settings aren't symmetrical so my layout looks a little ugly. I am generating a bunch of these forms with javascript. I do not want to inject large amounts of inline `style='margin:0px padding:0px'` stuff but it's the only way I can get it to work.

Comment: Show some code or an example. If you can get what you want with inline style attributes, you should be able to do it with a stylesheet.

Comment: I knew somebody would know the answer without any pictures :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a CSS selector, you can probably do this:

```
input[type=radio] { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Note however that older versions of IE [don't support attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp). For those, you can do:

```
<div class="radios">
   ...input tags...
</div>
```

and

```
.radios input { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

to catch the oldies. This would cut down the amount of presentational code while maintaining compatibility with ie6.

Comment: Didn't know about that syntax with square brackets. thx. However, I don't believe just doing it for input (as in your last example) will permeate through to the radio buttons.

Comment: it should, but in general form element rendering and formatting with CSS is very hit-or-miss, so sometimes things that *should* happen don't. At least IE6 is on the decline, so the attribute selectors aren't such a bad option.

Comment: Hm. Yes. Well the selector syntax works great. But I don't think I can use radio buttons for my application, it's too fugly...

Comment: Hah... too true. I suggest jQuery UI in that case: http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

Comment: I'll work up to jQuery one of these days. But this project here isn't gonna depend on it because i've invested too much in it to start over.